# How to get the text from the selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
string x = "<select><option value='2'>dfgdfh</option><option value='3'>cvncvn</option><option value='4'>cvn</option><option value='5'>dhdfh</option><option value='6'>dfhdfh</option><option selected="selected" value='7'>dfhdfh</option><option value='8'>dfgfdh</option><option value='12'>New type</option></select>"
```

How to get the text from the selected option?

Comment: From a string or when part of the DOM?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your string. Use single quotes for the `selected`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After fixing the syntax error in your string... :)

```
$(x).find("option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 3):

$(body).append(x);

$("select option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select id ="someid">
        <option value='2'>dfgdfh</option>
        <option value='3'>cvncvn</option>
        <option value='4'>cvn</option>
        <option value='5'>dhdfh</option>
        <option value='6'>dfhdfh</option>
        <option selected="selected" value='7'>dfhdfh</option>
        <option value='8'>dfgfdh</option>
        <option value='12'>New type</option>
    </select>
```

// string x =  $("#someid option[value='2']").text()

```
string x = $('#someid option:selected').text()
```

I think something like this might help.